# code trying to delete its discord message after sometime when it shouldnt

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I am creating a discord bot with node js and it keeps removing the message that has already been removed. everytime i try to register and it works succesfully it sometimes just removes the message after some time when it already has been removed so im assuming the error is that its trying to remove the already removed message again for some reason.
here is the error:

```
24.06 23:05:06 [Bot] /node_modules/@discordjs/rest/dist/index.js:640
24.06 23:05:06 [Bot] throw new DiscordAPIError(data, "code" in data ? data.code : data.error, status, method, url, requestData);
24.06 23:05:06 [Bot] ^
24.06 23:05:06 [Bot] DiscordAPIError[10008]: Unknown Message
24.06 23:05:06 [Bot] at handleErrors (/node_modules/@discordjs/rest/dist/index.js:640:13)
24.06 23:05:06 [Bot] at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
24.06 23:05:06 [Bot] at async SequentialHandler.runRequest (/node_modules/@discordjs/rest/dist/index.js:1021:23)
24.06 23:05:06 [Bot] at async SequentialHandler.queueRequest (/node_modules/@discordjs/rest/dist/index.js:862:14)
24.06 23:05:06 [Bot] at async REST.request (/node_modules/@discordjs/rest/dist/index.js:1387:22)
24.06 23:05:06 [Bot] at async InteractionWebhook.editMessage (/node_modules/discord.js/src/structures/Webhook.js:338:15)
24.06 23:05:06 [Bot] at async ChatInputCommandInteraction.editReply (/node_modules/discord.js/src/structures/interfaces/InteractionResponses.js:158:17) {
24.06 23:05:06 [Bot] requestBody: {
24.06 23:05:06 [Bot] files: [],
24.06 23:05:06 [Bot] json: {
24.06 23:05:06 [Bot] content: 'Deleting message..',
24.06 23:05:06 [Bot] tts: false,
24.06 23:05:06 [Bot] nonce: undefined,
24.06 23:05:06 [Bot] embeds: [],
24.06 23:05:06 [Bot] components: [],
24.06 23:05:06 [Bot] username: undefined,
24.06 23:05:06 [Bot] avatar_url: undefined,
24.06 23:05:06 [Bot] allowed_mentions: undefined,
24.06 23:05:06 [Bot] flags: undefined,
24.06 23:05:06 [Bot] message_reference: undefined,
24.06 23:05:06 [Bot] attachments: undefined,
24.06 23:05:06 [Bot] sticker_ids: undefined,
24.06 23:05:06 [Bot] thread_name: undefined
24.06 23:05:06 [Bot] }
24.06 23:05:06 [Bot] },
24.06 23:05:06 [Bot] rawError: { message: 'Unknown Message', code: 10008 },
24.06 23:05:06 [Bot] code: 10008,
24.06 23:05:06 [Bot] status: 404,
24.06 23:05:06 [Bot] method: 'PATCH',
24.06 23:05:06 [Bot] url: 'https://discord.com/api/v10/webhooks/1121408748972408884/aW50ZXJhY3Rpb246MTEyMjMwMTAyMzc4NTA3MDYwMjpNMTc0eGVLRHFiSUEwQUlpVkFCQnN4Ukw2eExNN3JFc3d3WVk0ZzB0NUN1Unk4cFpyQVJVNmlEcDgyamVGdDByZmlpakxCaDhKODNmVm1xOTNUVFcwVW9RbWZoT2RQNzRuOHJrb3lxemtzbGtsY0pDS2FrUENXR29CbWo0VnhMVg/messages/@original'
24.06 23:05:06 [Bot] }
```

this is my code:

```
const { EmbedBuilder, ActionRowBuilder, ButtonBuilder, ButtonStyle, SlashCommandBuilder } = require('discord.js');
const mysql = require('mysql');
const fetch = require('isomorphic-fetch');
require("dotenv").config();

module.exports = {
  data: new SlashCommandBuilder()
    .setName('register')
    .setDescription('Register your LoL account!')
    .addStringOption(option =>
      option.setName('username')
        .setDescription('Your LoL username!')
        .setRequired(true)),
  async execute(interaction) {
    try {
      var response = await interaction.reply({ content: '...', embeds: [], components: [], ephemeral: true });

      var leagueUsername = interaction.options.getString('username');
      const apiLink = `https://euw1.api.riotgames.com/lol/summoner/v4/summoners/by-name/${leagueUsername}?api_key=${process.env.LOLAPITOKEN}`;
  
      fetch(apiLink)
        .then(apiresponse => {
          if (!apiresponse.ok) {
            
            throw new Error('API request failed');
          }
          return apiresponse.json();
        })
        .then(data => {
          leagueUsername = data.name;
  
          const lolEmbed = new EmbedBuilder().setColor(0x0099FF).setDescription('To confirm this is your LoL account, change your profile picture in LoL to this picture').setImage('http://ddragon.leagueoflegends.com/cdn/10.18.1/img/profileicon/1.png');
          const discordUserID = interaction.user.id;
  
          const ready = new ButtonBuilder()
            .setCustomId('ready')
            .setLabel('Ready')
            .setStyle(ButtonStyle.Primary);
  
          const row = new ActionRowBuilder()
            .addComponents(ready);
  
          const connection = mysql.createConnection({
            host: process.env.DATABASEHOST,
            user: process.env.DATABASEUSER,
            password: process.env.DATABASEPASSWORD,
            database: process.env.DATABASENAME
          });
  
          let connectionClosed = false; // Flag to track if the connection is closed
  
          connection.connect(err => {
            if (err) {
              console.error(err);
              interaction.editReply({ content: 'Something went wrong with the database connection :(', embeds: [], components: [] });
              return;
            }
            console.log('Connected to the database!');
  
            const searchForUsersQuery = 'SELECT * FROM LoLregistration WHERE discordID = ?';
            connection.query(searchForUsersQuery, [discordUserID], (err, results) => {
              if (err) {
                console.error('Error executing query:', err);
                return interaction.editReply({ content: 'Something went wrong with the query.', embeds: [], components: [] });
              }
              if (results.length !== 0) {
                connection.end();
                console.log("Connection closed.");
                connectionClosed = true; // Set the flag to true
                interaction.editReply({ content: 'Already registered.', embeds: [], components: [] });
                setTimeout(() => {
                  return interaction.deleteReply();
                }, 5000);
              } else {
                response = interaction.editReply({
                  content: '',
                  embeds: [lolEmbed],
                  components: [row],
                });
              }
            });
          });
  
          const collectorFilter = i => i.user.id === interaction.user.id;
  
          response.awaitMessageComponent({ filter: collectorFilter, time: 90_000 })
            .then(async confirmation => {
              if (confirmation.customId === 'ready') {
                await confirmation.update({ content: `...`, components: [] });
                fetch(apiLink)
                .then(apiresponse2 => {
                  if (!apiresponse2.ok) {
                    throw new Error('API request failed');
                  }
                  return apiresponse2.json();
                })
                .then(data1 => {
                  if (data1.profileIconId === 1) {
                    const userData = { discordID: discordUserID, usernameLoL: leagueUsername };
                    const insertUserQuery = 'INSERT INTO LoLregistration SET ?';
                    connection.query(insertUserQuery, userData, (err, result) => {
                      if (err) {
                        console.error('Error inserting data:', err);
                        interaction.editReply({ content: 'Something went wrong with registering :(', embeds: [], components: [] });
                      } else {
                        console.log('Data inserted successfully!');
                        interaction.editReply({ content: 'Thank you for registering! :)', embeds: [], components: [] });
                      }
                      if (!connectionClosed) { // Check the flag before closing the connection
                        connection.end();
                        console.log("Connection closed.");
                      }
                      setTimeout(() => {
                        return interaction.deleteReply();
                      }, 5000);
                    });
                  } else {
                    interaction.editReply({ content: 'Incorrect profile picture.', embeds: [], components: [] });
                    if (!connectionClosed) { // Check the flag before closing the connection
                      connection.end();
                      console.log("Connection closed.");
                    }
                    setTimeout(() => {
                      return interaction.deleteReply();
                    }, 5000);
                  }
                }).catch(error => {
                  console.error(error);
                });
              }
            })
            .catch(e => {
              interaction.editReply({ content: 'Deleting message..', embeds: [], components: [] });
              if (!connectionClosed) { // Check the flag before closing the connection
                connection.end();
                console.log("Connection closed.");
              }
              setTimeout(() => {
                interaction.deleteReply();
              }, 5000);
            });
        })
        .catch(error => {
          console.error(error);
          interaction.editReply({ content: 'No summoner found.', embeds: [], components: [] });
          setTimeout(() => {
            return interaction.deleteReply();
          }, 5000);
        });
    } catch (error) {
      if (error.code === 10008) {
        /*if (!connectionClosed) { // Check the flag before closing the connection
          connection.end();
          console.log("Connection closed.");
        }*/
        console.error('The message could not be found or identified.');
        /*interaction.editReply({ content: 'No response. Deleting message.', embeds: [], components: [] });
          setTimeout(() => {
            return interaction.deleteReply();
          }, 5000);*/
      } else {
        console.error(error);
      }
    }
  },
};
```

i have tried catching the error code but to no avail. the bot keeps crashing when this happens.

Comment: You have `interaction.deleteReply()` in a `setTimeout()` call that runs after five seconds. It probably has something to do with that. Perhaps that interaction was already deleted?

Comment: I also noticed that you have two separate calls to `interaction.deleteReply()` Is it possible that `interaction` refers to the same interaction in both cases?

Comment: hey i fixed the issue by removing one of the `deleteReply()` functions because it was messing with my `collectorFilter` aswell, hence why it was trying to delete a already deleted message